# Charge density of a point charge

Tags: electrostatics, charge, density, dirac-delta-distributions

Is it right to say that the charge density of a point charge is infinity? if I were to take a uniformly charged ball with radius R and take the limit $R\to 0$, won't I get an infinite charge density at the origin because there will be a finite charge divided by a volume which goes to 0? 
I know you can use the delta dirac function to describe such situations, but I'm not there yet. Generally, is it true to say the charge density of a point charge is 0 everywhere and infinite at the origin?

Comment: You just contradicted yourself in the last sentence.  The density can be infinite while the charge is NOT.  So it is not correct to say that the charge is 0 everywhere and infinite at the origin.  Q is NOT infinite, rho is.

Comment: Whoops, a mistake. I meant the charge density. Is the density indeed infinity then?

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Comment: @DavidZ It is very annoying when a question is  made duplicate because the system does not have consideration of somebody  taking time to write with references, trying to educate and elucidate. I usually write a place holder, but this time I forgot. It did not look like a question to be closed.From now on I will always write a first sentence place holder.

Comment: @annav Please don't. Placeholders are not an appropriate use of the answer box.

Comment: @DavidZ  Well, cut in the middle, or just before the end,  of writing an answer that has taken some time to put references in,  even though instead of saying "this question is no longer accepting answers" it could say "in ten minutes this question will not be accepting answer", is appropriate? We are talking here of ten minutes.

Comment: @annav The whole point of blocking answering when a question is put on hold is to have people not post answers to the question. So delaying the actual hold just to give a warning period would be counterproductive. In fact, if a question is put on hold, one would generally expect experienced site members to have recognized that the question is not suitable for the site and refrained from answering it even _before_ it was put on hold.

Comment: @DavidZ It as made duplicate, not closed. And  my answer did not fit the duplicate question, where I usually transfer answers when this happens. I use the "place holder" when I expect it to be closed . As I have said before, my aim is to gently educate, where possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106587/discussion-between-david-z-and-anna-v).

Comment: @DavidZ sorry, it is 9:30 in the morning here,  and I have chores to do, before the sun gets too hot.I put the question on physics meta, for giving 10 minutes warning feature